# How could I check for anything after an Input

Tags: python

I have the /add Command in my code and Want to know how I could check if anything is after the word. How could I check for anything, not a specific word just a term in python for literally anything

```
if command == "/add" + *anything*:
     print("yay!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you want to check that the `inputName` is in the list of the `checkName`, then it can be done like follows:

```
inputName = input("Enter Command (do /help for a list of commands): ")
# Right here I want the name in the command input added to the list for example /add Joe
checkName = ["Joe", "Katy", "Jack"]
if inputName in checkName:
    patients.append(input_name)
```

Comment: From their description, it sounds like they want to check that the input _starts_ with particular text, regardless of what the input _ends_ with. You seem to be separating the parameter out into a separate input, and looking for an exact match.

Comment: Hello @Jeremy, the Terrible Game Developer edited his post. My answer is for his initiate post

Comment: Aha, thank you for pointing that out. That's really frustrating—and poor practice on Stack Overflow when answers have already been contributed. (Obviously, editing a question is fine, but changing it to an effectively new question is not.)

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions:

`strip`:

```
name.strip("/add ")
```

`slice`:

```
name[4:]
```

`split`:

```
name.split("")[1]
```